# MongoDB: returning documents in order until a condition match

Tags: mongodb

In a MongoDB collection, I have documents with a "position" field for ordering and an optional "date" field, e.g.

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "doc1",
    "position": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "doc2",
    "position": 2,
    "date": "2021-05-20T08:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": "doc3",
    "position": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "doc4",
    "position": 4,
    "date": "2021-05-20T08:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

I would like the query this collection to get the documents "before" a specified date, in position order. The algorithm would be:

1. find the first element whose date is "after" the specified date
2. return all the documents whose position is less than the position of the element found, sorted by "position"

I have implemented this algorithm naïvely with 2 independent queries. However, I suspect it can be done with a single call to the database, but I have no idea how to proceed. Maybe with an aggregation pipeline?

Can someone give me a clue how this can be done?

EDIT: Here are the current queries I use (roughly):

```js
limit_element = db.getCollection('collection').find({
    "date": { "$gte":  ISODate("2021-05-20T08:00:00.000Z") }
}).sort({
    "position": 1
}).limit(1)

position = limit_element['position']

elements = db.getCollection('collection').find({
    "position": { "$lt": position }
}).sort({
    "position": 1
})
```

Comment: can two dates be same? your example shows, If it can, which date you need to take.  Assume your 4th document date is greater than 2nd document date. And you are passing now second document date. so do you need to get the 3rd document also which doesn't have date?

Comment: What query did you come up with?

Comment: The dates are increasing in the elements sorted in position order, but may be equal between consecutive elements. So that's why I take the first element whose date condition does not match anymore and get all the elements whose index is lower. In that case, it is guaranteed that all the elements (having a date) have a date below the specified one, but are returned in position order.

Comment: @D.SM I have added the queries to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation pipeline with two match clauses. Essentially its the same thing as you do now but within one DB access so a bit faster. With aggregation you can acess results from the previus stage to use in the next stage. If that is worth it you have to decide. I think your naive approach is sensible. In any case this a conditional problem so you will have to first find one and then do the other. Difference is just where you do the steps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mon concerns are: 1. what if someone change the collection between my 2 queries? 2. I need to optimize this part of the application code, so I would like to avoid doing 2 queries when I can do a single query. I think the aggregation pipeline addresses both issues, right?

Comment: That is correct, yes. With the $ operator in the aggregation pipeline you can reference the result fields of the previous stage.